# Set drop down list value from model in edit menu

Tags: razor, model-view-controller

I have a drop down list I populate in my view.

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AmPm, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AmPm, new List<SelectListItem>
                {                    
                    new SelectListItem{Text="AM", Value="1"},
                    new SelectListItem{Text="PM", Value="2"},
                    new SelectListItem{Text=@"N\A", Value="3", Selected=true},
                }, new { id = "amPmDropDownSelect", @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AmPm, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I come to edit a record, that has a value, I would like the drop downlist to be selected on the value stored in the model.  Is it possible to do this without jquery?

when loading the drop down list over an empty model, I wanted "Text=@"N\A", Value="3" to be the selected value and thought adding Selected=true would work but it always defaults to display the first one in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `AmPm` property of your view model to the value of the option you want to select, in your GET action.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var vm = new YourViewModel();
    vm.AmPm="3";
    return View(vm);
}
```

Now the `DropDownListFor` helper method will select the option item with the value "3".

If the type of `AmPm` property is `int`, you can set the int value.

```
 vm.AmPm=3;
```

You can read the value from your entity and set that instead of hard coding to 3, For example

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{       
    var e=db.Tasks.Find(id);
    var vm = new YourViewModel() { Title = e.Title };
    vm.AmPm = e.AmPm;  // This line sets the selected value 
    return View(vm);
}
```

Also you can now remove the `Selected=true` from the third `SelectListItem` object you are adding to the list which will be used to build the options

Comment: Thanks I had already tried passing the model in without luck but it works now so i must have made an error!